# How can I show only an .htaccess file in the Finder?

Tags: macos, finder

I'm a web developer. I really need to use `.htaccess` file.
How can make Finder show only the `.htaccess` file and not all the file prefixed with `.`?

I am running OS X Lion.

Comment: Good question!! I need this too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To my best knowledge, you cannot selectively display dot files in Finder. However, if you just need a way to easily open them via Finder, you could create a symlink to the file in its directory, omitting the dot in the name, i.e.:

1. open Terminal, `cd` into your folder;
2. `ln -s $PWD/.htaccess $PWD/htaccess`.

You can then open the file by double-clicking the newly created link, select an editor in the link’s context menu etc. However, if you want to copy, up- or download your `.htaccess` file, you are stuck with Terminal, full display of all dot files, or temporarily renaming the file (to `_htaccess`, say).

Answer (score 1):

Tried many method, the best way for me is use [Houdini](https://sites.google.com/site/elementninety3/houdini).
Houdini can easily hide and display all hidden.

Comment: Didn’t you specifically ask for a solution that does **not** display all dot files (“How can make Finder show only the `.htaccess` file and not all the file prefixed with `.`?”)? Houdini doesn’t do that, AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for the app, at least this is less painful than opening the terminal.