# Search all hidden .htaccess files inside a folder and run a terminal command?

Tags: terminal, automator, filesystem

Searching for the issue, I found this Q&A:
[How can I show only an .htaccess file in the Finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/28412/21950)

> [...] you could create a symlink to the file in its directory, omitting the dot in the name:
>
> 1. open Terminal, cd into your folder
> 2. `ln -s $PWD/.htaccess $PWD/htaccess`

**Is there** some kind of *terminal batch* to search for all .htaccess files inside a folder (i.e.: `/public_html`) and apply the symlink?

**Or would** it be a combination of Automator and Terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to the initial directory (`public_html` in the question) and run

```
find . -name '.htaccess' -print | while read f; do
    ln -s "$PWD/$f" "$PWD/${f//.htaccess}htaccess"
done
```

PS: I did some rudimentary testing but please make a backup before you run it anyway.

Comment: Ha! -> small test ok -> so, run all the development folder -> good to go ! . . Much appreciated!